# SmartGWT ListGrid - exclude field from selection

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I would like to ask for your help to solve the following problem.

I have a SmartGwt ListGrid wich has multiple rows in it.
This ListGrid has a SelectionChangedHandler which works just fine.

I added a special column (ListGridField) to this ListGrid, on which basically I want to prevent the selectionChangeEvent to trigger when clicked.

This special column has its own recordclickHandler.

I only want to EXCLUDE this column form changing the selected record in the ListGrid.

Is there any way to do so in your knowledge?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event for row selection doesn't tell you which cell you clicked on, hence no way of telling which column, I think you'll need to make cells selectable, and ignore the event if the cell is in the excluded column.

```
myGrid.setCanSelectCells(true);

myGrid.addCellSelectionChangedHandler(new CellSelectionChangedHandler() {
  public void onCellSelectionChanged(CellSelectionChangedEvent event) {  
    CellSelection selection = countryGrid.getCellSelection();

    //use to determine if excluded column is clicked:
    int[][] selectedCells = selection.getSelectedCells();

    //use to get selected row: 
    ListGridRecord record = selection.getSelectedRecord();

    //etc...
  }
}
```